# Build errors when installing neovim from source in Debian ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'

Tags: neovim

I am facing some build errors in building Neovim from source in Debian (MxLinux). I tried the package installer and was able to install Neovim, but it is an older version. So, I installed all dependencies as mentioned on the wiki https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim#build-prerequisite

The `ninja` and `cmake` among dependencies I installed from pip3 with the `--user` option, to avail a more updated version than the `apt` repository.

The `sudo make install` ran into error first

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles'   \
     $HOME/neovim//third-party
/bin/sh: 2: cmake: not found
```

So, I installed the `cmake` from `apt`. The error ceased but a new error crept in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "$HOME/.local/bin/ninja", line 5, in <module>
      from ninja import ninja

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'
```

I have `ninja-build` installed from `apt`. I also have `ninja` from pip3 at the $PATH.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/41504/10604

Answer (score 0):

Ninja was installed on my machine and already in my path in 2 places, I don't know if this was the source of the issue, but I got it working by taking ownership of the system-level python libraries and installation directories:

```
sudo chown <my username> /usr/local/lib/python* -R
```

and

```
sudo chown <my username> /usr/lib/python* -R
```

`-R` makes the changes above recursively- effectively changing all child files' and directories' ownership to my user.

I then installed ninja with pip again- which installed it for the whole system:

```
pip install ninja
```

Note- you can find your username by using:

```
whoami
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, generally. Perhaps you needed `pip install --user`, make sure the corresponding directories are earlier than system dirs on your PATH, and (since this is the second recent question I've seen about NeoVim's build process) make sure the build process correctly accounts for different locations of needed libraries and programs.