# How come `pip install cmake` is not enough to build neovim?

Tags: neovim

I just built `neovim` from source for the first time on linux (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64), and I got stuck for a while on something silly.

In the [Build prerequisites](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim#build-prerequisites) I saw that `CMake` was (of course) required, so I `pip install`ed it as suggested, and it was also listed in the `apt install` command for Ubuntu / Debian requirements. At first I thought "I just installed `cmake` with `pip` so I don't need to install it again", but it turns out I was wrong because I was unable to run `make install` successfully until I ran `sudo apt install cmake`.

The error was `cmake: not found` at step `build/.ran-deps-cmake`, although cmake **was** already installed (`cmake --version` worked as expected).

Is there a reason for that? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Probably an issue of PATH and searching for the command. I suggest discussing with NeoVim maintainers on GitHub.

Comment: Alright, thank you for you feedback, I will open an issue on Github. I wanted to ask here first in case I had missed something but I guess it might actually be a minor issue.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37475/10604